# mailto: is not working in js (goes to outlook or something that is not gmail

Tags: javascript

Today, when I was coding, I want to use the `mailto:` tag but it does not work.
maybe my program is wrong, or my computer is bad.
How could I change what program I can use? (like outlook to gmail in web browser)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we specify a particular email client while using href=mailto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754478/can-we-specify-a-particular-email-client-while-using-href-mailto)

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not wrong and your computer is not bad. Your browser simply hands over the details of the mialto URL to whatever the default mail client is. Where that mapping exists depends on what browser you are using. But most implementations are predicated on the mail client (specifically the MUA) being a standalone program on the local computer - so it may be trick to convince the browser to use a URL.

OTOH, you can explicitly reconfigure Firefox and Chrome to use a web MUA (including Gmail) via [navigator.registerProtocolHandler()](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/Getting-Gmail-to-handle-all-mailto-links-with-registerProtocolHandler)