# Opening Outlook from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, outlook, mailto

I have used `mailto:` but `mailto:` opens the default email client on the system.
Is there any way to open specific mail client such as outlook from javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we specify a particular email client while using href=mailto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754478/can-we-specify-a-particular-email-client-while-using-href-mailto)

Comment: *See the post below that uses ActiveX:* [opening Outlook through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776672/opening-outlook-through-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [opening Outlook through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776672/opening-outlook-through-javascript)

Comment: just as a UX note: this may really peeve people off. I for one am a Linux user, so Outlook isn't even a thing for me, and on Windows, Thunderbird is my client (as it is on my Linux Partition). Is there any real reason for wanting Outlook instead of the user's preference?

Comment: Please provide what you have tried. Post your question as a complete reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve here are some hints on how: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask